# Write onto RTMP stream using XUGGLER

Tags: red5, rtmp, xuggler

I am working on a project, I want to write packets on to an RTMP container.

- What I have achieved is:

  1. To start an app which listens for RTMP requests using RED5. Lets say rtmp://localhost/myapp
  2. I could open IContainer with IContainerFormat's output format give as ("flv", "rtmp://localhost/myapp/test", null)
- Whats going wrong is :

  1. I want to write packets on to this RTMP channel that is opened for me.

     - Issue is FFMPEG starts giving error 32. A bit of search related to this error showed that this is happens usually because there is a lag between client - server data consumption. But I really was not able to solve this issue. I have searched a lot but everyone is crying about the same issue. The error i get is :

> 12:57:20.242 [Thread-0] ERROR org.ffmpeg - WriteN, RTMP send error 32 (129 bytes)
>       12:57:20.246 [Thread-0] ERROR org.ffmpeg - WriteN, RTMP send error 32 (45 bytes)
>       12:57:20.246 [Thread-0] ERROR org.ffmpeg - WriteN, RTMP send error 9 (42 bytes)

And this is the error i receive on Red5 Server

```
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - Provider connect
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - Stream start
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - Provider connect
[ERROR] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Error decoding buffer
org.red5.server.net.protocol.ProtocolException: Error during decoding
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder.decode(RTMPProtocolDecoder.java:203) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder.decodeBuffer(RTMPProtocolDecoder.java:122) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPMinaProtocolDecoder.decode(RTMPMinaProtocolDecoder.java:61) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:225) [mina-core-2.0.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:434) [mina-core-2.0.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:46) [mina-core-2.0.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:793) [mina-core-2.0.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapter.java:119) [mina-core-2.0.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:434) [mina-core-2.0.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:426) [mina-core-2.0.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:638) [mina-core-2.0.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:598) [mina-core-2.0.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:587) [mina-core-2.0.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$400(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:61) [mina-core-2.0.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:969) [mina-core-2.0.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64) [mina-core-2.0.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_07]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_07]
    at org.red5.io.amf.Input.bufferToString(Input.java:275) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.io.amf.Input.getString(Input.java:258) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.io.amf.Input.readPropertyName(Input.java:565) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.io.amf.Input.readKeyValues(Input.java:351) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.io.amf.Input.readSimpleObject(Input.java:501) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.io.amf.Input.readObject(Input.java:537) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder.decodeStreamMetadata(RTMPProtocolDecoder.java:978) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder.decodeMessage(RTMPProtocolDecoder.java:564) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder.decodePacket(RTMPProtocolDecoder.java:385) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder.decode(RTMPProtocolDecoder.java:190) [red5.jar:na]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
[WARN] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Closing connection because decoding failed: RTMPMinaConnection from 127.0.0.1 : 44814 to localhost (in: 3569 out 3521 )
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - Close
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - Provider disconnect
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - Provider disconnect
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Connecting to: [Scope@5f524524 Depth = 2, Path = '/default/myapp', Name = 'test']
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Remembering client buffer on stream: 300
[ERROR] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.service.ServiceInvoker - Method FCSubscribe with parameters [teststream] not found in org.red5.core.Application@b9e19da
[WARN] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.stream.PlayEngine - Subscribe to teststream provider failed
```

I am new to media streaming, so not sure if I am missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is a different chance then debugging the Java Source code of RTMPProtocolDecoder.

But I don't know what Red5 version you are using.

RTMPProtocolDecoder.java:203 
=> In the latest version of Red5/Sources your exception is in line 147:
http://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/java/server/trunk/src/org/red5/server/net/rtmp/codec/RTMPProtocolDecoder.java#147

And also added with some comments. I guess first thing you would need to do is to update to latest red5. Based on that you can then debug and ask for more help.

Comment: I started with Red5 1.0-RC2, But it was having some issues with server applications so after a lot of search finally I switched back to Red5 0.9.1 version where basic NetConnection is happening and my server app is accepting client requests.

Comment: You will need to update to latest version at some point, there are many memory leak fixes in later versions. You will need those if you plan to switch to production with your app at some point.

Comment: This is the decoder of Red5 0.9.1 http://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/java/server/trunk/src/org/red5/server/net/rtmp/codec/RTMPProtocolDecoder.java?r=4047#202

Comment: You should get he source code into an IDE, I can hardly now try to reverse engeneer your stack trace :)

Comment: As you suggested I am switching on to Red5 RC2, and it has some issues with configuration i guess. It is never able to find scope of my test application. I have created a demo app using Red5 eclipse plugin. Do you have any idea about it ? Same app runs on Red5 0.9.1 and 0.9.0.
[INFO] [NioProcessor-2] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action connect
'[INFO] [NioProcessor-2] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Setting object encoding to AMF3
[INFO] [NioProcessor-2] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Scope myapp not found on localhos'

Comment: you should be looking at red5.log/error.log and the general stack trace. I guess your webapp is simply not loaded at all because the configs changed. If you have an exact error I guess I can tell you want went wrong.

Comment: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'clientRegistry': : Cannot find class [org.red5.server.WebScope] for bean with name 'web.scope' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.red5.server.WebScope; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.red5.server.WebScope] for bean with name 'web.scope' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.red5.server.WebScope

Comment: <bean id="web.scope" class="org.red5.server.scope.WebScope" init-method="register"> is the new definitions. Fix this path in your red5-web.xml

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17445/discussion-between-amd-and-seba-wagner)

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the answer. Do not rely on Red5 eclipse plugin, it generates code that is not compatible with Red 5 1.0RC2. 
Red5 1.0 RC 2 works fine with a configuration change  in red5-web.xml. The app starts working and I could start a stream on the container using xuggler.

Thank you  @seba.wagner.